# Content of the <div> is lost after the eventListener function is completed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here's my Html. the output will be str.

```
<div id="response_container"> 
     //str 
</div>
```

And here's the javascript

```
const form = document.getElementById('search_form');
const htmlcontainer = document.getElementById('response_container');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function()
    {
        console.log("Inside sendQuery()");
        var to_search = document.querySelector('#item_to_search').value;
        var xmlObject = createObject();
        console.log(xmlObject);
        xmlObject.open("GET", "getData.php?search="+ to_search +"&srch_submit=search");
        xmlObject.send(null);
        xmlObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlObject.readyState == 4 && xmlObject.status == 200)
            {
                var doc = xmlObject.responseXML;
                var child = doc.documentElement;
                var content = child.firstChild.data;
                console.log(content);
                var arr = JSON.parse(content);

                for(var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++)
                {
                    str = "<br><span>Name: "+ arr[i][0] +" Roll No: "+ arr[i][1] +"</span>";
                    htmlcontainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', str);
                    /*htmlcontainer.innerHTML = str;*/

                }
                /*htmlcontainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', content);*/

            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
```

This ajax code works with another php file and returns all the names in database that matches the string entered. But names do not show up in this div that has `id="response_container"`. I tried halting program in debugger and found that as for loop proceeds, all names does show up in the  but vanishes after the eventListener finishes its work. Please help. Is there any way I can fix this?I want names in . thank u

Comment: Is the page reloading? It doesn't appear you are preventing the default submit process

Comment: @charlietfl where should i add event.preventdefault??

Comment: [Event.preventDefault (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 3):

Prevent the browser default form submit process

Change

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
```

To

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // other code is same
```

Comment: @D... — sending the contents of the form to the URL specified by the forms action attribute and displaying the page returned by the server in the main window.

Comment: form will send the data from inputs to the url in `action` using whatever the `method` of form is. If neither exist it will send to current page url as GET causing the page to reload.

Comment: Got it ,Thank you both of u.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the form from 'submitting' which is basically wiping out your div because of the page reload.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //....
}
```